# assign a case to specific user

Tags: trigger

I'm using LiveHelpNow which is an Agent Chat integration tool with Salesforce. the LiveHelpNow console can assign the case to Queue and does not have the ability to assign it to a specific salesforce user.
i've been trying to do OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(); so it would assign the user session Id. Also I've tried OwnerId = CreatedById and not working either.

```
trigger LiveHelpCaseOwnerChange on Case (before insert) {

for (case c : Trigger.new)
{

        c.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any active assignment rules?

Comment: yes, but it's not related to OwnerId or CreatedById.

Comment: I think that if assignment rules are executed because the client sets the `AssignmentRuleHeader` that it doesn't matter that you've set the `ownerId` in the trigger. You would need to reassign the user _after_ the assignment rules execute by stashing the currentUser in some other field in the Case. I'd like to be wrong here so others may jump in. See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the assignment to `Process Builder`, it will execute after `Assignment Rules` and hence cannot be overridden by them. You should be able to set the value as `$User.Id`.

Comment: might be hard as OP is using appexchange product and pkg may be setting AssignmentRuleHeader but your solution should work to reassign after initial assignment rules - although if queue is configured to get emails, some spurious emails may ensue

Comment: @cropredy Emails are not sent until final commit, so it should be okay.

Comment: @sfdcfox. Maybe I'm not understanding something. If assignment rules are automatically triggered by the app exchange product and the rules assign to a queue and that rule is configured to send email, then even if process builder reruns the assignment rules and assigns to a user, that first assignment will send email to the queue members. No?

Comment: I've removed/Inactivated case assignment rule. the cases now generated from LiveHelpNow, however the create by always is default to my name, even though the support settings is set to Queue.

Comment: @Templar If you want to specify `CreatedById`, you need to [Enable Create Audit Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-specify-the-values-in-Created-By-Created-Date-Last-Modified-By-ID-Last-Modified-Date&language=en_US).

Comment: it is own, but it always default to me as creator, even if I login under different user. Agene these cases are created with LiveHelpNow and not though salesforce case->new Case.

Comment: Yeah I think creating the record as a delegated user still sets the `CreatedById` to yourself. You'll need to enable that permission if you want to do that.

Comment: how to do you make Case.OwnerId = $User.Id in process builder?

Comment: can i do in formula function Text([case].OwnerId = [User].Id) in order to replace the current owner Id with current user id ?

Comment: Formula cannot change the value of another field.